# How do I run one version of a web app while developing the next version?

Tags: django, version-control

I just finished a Django app that I want to get some outside user feedback on. I'd like to launch one version and then fork a private version so I can incorporate feedback and add more features. I'm planning to do lots of small iterations of this process. I'm new to web development; how do websites typically do this? Is it simply a matter of copying my Django project folder to another directory, launching the server there, and continuing my dev work in the original directory? Or would I want to use a version control system instead? My intuition is that it's the latter, but if so, it seems like a huge topic with many uses (e.g. collaboration, which doesn't apply here) and I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1) Seperate URLs** www.yoursite.com vs test.yoursite.com.  you can also do www.yoursite.com and www.yoursite.com/development, etc..  You could also create a /beta or /staging..

**2) Keep seperate databases, one for production, and one for development.** Write a script that will copy your live database into a dev database. Keep one database for each type of site you create.  (You may want to create a beta or staging database for your tester).. Do your own work in the dev database.  If you change the database structure, save the changes as a .sql file that can be loaded and run on the live site database when you turn those changes live.

**3) Merge features into your different sites with version control.**  I am currently playing with a subversion setup for web apps that has my stable (trunk), one for staging, and one for development.   Development tags + branches get merged into staging, and then staging tags/branches get merged into stable.  Version control will let you manage your source code in any way you want.  You will have to find a methodology that works for you and use it.

**4) Consider build automation.**  It will publish your site for you automatically. Take a look at http://ant.apache.org/.  It can drive a lot of automatically checking out your code and uploading it to each specific site as you might need.

**5) Toy of the month:** There is a utility called [cUrl](http://curl.haxx.se/) that you may find valuable.  It does a lot from the command line.  This might be okay for you to do in case you don't want to use all or any of Ant.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You would typically use version control, and have two domains: your-site.com and test.your-site.com.  Then your-site.com would always update to trunk which is the current latest, shipping version.  You would do your development in a branch of trunk and test.your-site.com would update to that.  Then you periodically merge changes from your development branch to trunk.

Comment: I tend to keep my final staging on the same box as production. I had running's in the past where there where small discrepancies between stage and live, having it on the same box solves those issues quite a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Jas Panesar has the best answer if you are asking this from a development standpoint, certainly. That is, if you're just asking how to easily keep your new developments separate from the site that is already running. However, if your question was actually asking how to run both versions simultaniously, then here's my two cents.

Your setup has a lot to do with this, but I always recommend running process-based web servers in the first place. That is, not to use threaded servers (less relevant to this question) and not embedding in the web server (that is, not using mod_python, which is the relevant part here). So, you have one or more processes getting HTTP requests from your web server (Apache, Nginx, Lighttpd, etc.). Now, when you want to try something out live, without affecting your normal running site, you can bring up a process serving requests that never gets the regular requests proxied to it like the others do. That is, normal users don't see it.

You can setup a subdomain that points to this one, and you can install middleware that redirects "special" user to the beta version. This allows you to unroll new features to some users, but not others.

Now, the biggest issues come with database changes. Schema migration is a big deal and something most of us never pay attention to. I think that running side-by-side is great, because it forces you to do schema migrations correctly. That is, you can't just shut everything down and run lengthy schema changes before bringing it back up. You'd never see any remotely important site doing that.

The key is those small steps. You need to always have two versions of your code able to access the same database, so changes you make for the new code need to not break the old code. This breaks down into a few steps you can always make:

- You can add a column with a default value, or that is optional. The new code can use it, and the old code can ignore it.
- You can update the live version with code that knows to use a new column, at which point you can make it required.
- You can make the new version ignore a column, and when it becomes the main version, you can delete that column.

You can make these small steps to migrate between any schemas. You can iteratively add a new column that replaces an old one, roll out the new code, and remove the old column, all without interrupting service.

That said, its your first web app? You can probably break it. You probably have few users :-) But, it is fantastic you're even asking this question. Many "professionals" fair to ever ask it, and even then fewer answer it.

Comment: I really like your points about schema migration.  I think there is room for interpretation on running side-by-side.  I have been able to run all three (production/staging/dev) sites on one server with seperate databases, it's worked great.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is have an export a copy of my SVN repository and put the files on the live production server, and then keep a virtual machine with a development working copy, and submit the changes to the repo when Im done.